# AWS SQS access policy block default access to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, policy, identity-management

I have a SQS setup in AWS with an access policy which allows another account's SNS to push message,
and an instance with an IAM role allowing the instance to communicate with the queue.

I found that if I apply the access policy of SQS, the instance cannot access the SQS. Removing it, the instance can work with the queue.

Is there an explanation which can explan this?

Remove the access policy from the queue, works;

SQS Policy as following:

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Id": "sqspolicy",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "First",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
                },
                "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
                "Resource": "${module.elmo-s-rem-sqs-user-sync-service.primary_queue_arn}",
                "Condition": {
                    "ArnEquals": {
                        "aws:SourceArn": "${local.pivot_topic_arn}"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Have a tried by removing the Principal part, that could let the simulator pass. But the sns couldn't publish message any more.

Comment: Show us the policy

Comment: Yes. Added as show in the question